# Web application to backup my mobile phone contacts

Tags: webapp-rec

I am looking for a web application that can backup and synchronise my mobile phone contacts.

[Nokia, Symbian OS, S60]

Comment: which mobile phone platform do you use?  that would be so helpful.

Comment: @Fosco Nokia, Symbian OS, S60

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Nokia phone, just use [Ovi Contacts](http://www.ovi.com/services/). It has a web and a Symbian client (comes pre-installed on S60v5 and higher). And best of all, it's free. I

t integrates well with my phone (I have an X6), for example allowing me to call someone either from my phone's memory, my SIM card, or my Ovi collection.

Comment: +1 it works. it simple. i think, nokia knows better about her products. thanks.

Answer (score 4):

For my iPhone, I use Google Sync, which works flawlessly. If you go to the [Google Sync homepage](http://www.google.com/mobile/sync/), you'll see that they also have Contacts sync for Nokia S60. I would recommend trying Google Sync out.

This will sync your contacts with Gmail's contacts, so you can even access them through any web browser.

Comment: I use Symbian as well and would vouch for Google sync for contacts. Its definitely even better than Ovi IMO.

Comment: aaaah..google will soon take over the world! :) +1 thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I use [this](https://www.bloove.com/en) for my Nokia n93 (s60v3).

Answer (score 0):

I use a backup service called http://www.forgotyourphone.com/

It backed up all of my contacts, BBM Pins and appointments.

> Forgot Your Phone is a reliable and user friendly way of storing your mobile phone contacts, email addresses, appointments and notes. With a FREE online account you are able to access this information anytime, anywhere!